# foreach doesnt do loops for my search

Tags: php, arrays

i have a foreach where i want to compare some strings from two arrays

output of variable $count_land

```
Array
(
    ["US"] => 186
    ["DE"] => 44
    ["BR"] => 15
    ["FR"] => 3
    ["other"] => 7
)
```

Other array:

```
 $all_lands_array = ["CN", "DE", "US", "EU", "RU", "BR", "GB", "NL", "LU", "other", "IT"];
```

what i need is every key in the $all_lands_array that have the same letters from the $count_land array and save them in another variable

that means i need to get US, DE, BR, FR, other and save them in a new variable

i hope you understand what i need :)

this is my loop but it doesnt find any match.. but why?

```
foreach($all_lands_array as $lands){
    if($lands == $count_land)
        return "match";
    else
        return "no match!";
    }
```

Comment: you are comparing strings with arrays

Comment: Just search with `in_array()` in the keys, which you get with: `array_keys($count_land)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you just loop through one array and then check the value against the whole other array.

**Checking for country codes:**

```
$count_land = array
(
    "US" => 186,
    "DE" => 44,
    "BR" => 15,
    "FR" => 3,
    "other" => 7
);

$all_lands_array = array("CN", "DE", "US", "EU", "RU", "BR", "GB", "NL", "LU", "other", "IT");

$matches = array();   


foreach($count_land as $key => $val){
        if(in_array($key, $all_lands_array)){
            $matches[$key] = $val; // add matches to array;
        }else{
           // do nothing
        }
    }

print_r($matches);die;
```

**returns:**

Array ( [US] => 186 [DE] => 44 [BR] => 15 [other] => 7 )

Comment: i still dont get any match.. i mean, at least 5 lands should match.. but i still get nothing

Comment: Because of the return. The return exists the loop, I have updated my answer to catch the matches.

Comment: this just gives me an undefined variable matches :o

Comment: Updated my answer, please check it.

Comment: it still gives me an : undefined variable $matches :O

Comment: okay i did a mistake - but it just gives me nothing.. an empty array :o

Comment: I have tested my code, it is correct and works. Maybe you just have missed some changes relatively to your code in the question. Please copy my code completely and test it.

Comment: i believe it works with you - but it doesnt with me :o i copied at exactly from your answer but i just get an empty array :o with just nothing - i dont think the code is false but i really cant explain why this doesnt work

Comment: not the first array but the rest - i get the first array dynamicly.. so i cant just copy it - but in my $count_land array is just the same like that in your answer

Comment: i found the mistake like 5 minutes ago :) my mistake was that $all_lands array.. i needed to do a ' ' bevor and after the " " - like ' " DE " ' :) thanks for help anyway :) –

Answer (score 1):

You have to save the countries in a variable as an array and use in_array to check if an element is in that array:

```
    $found = array();
    $countries = array_keys($count_land); //stores: US,DE..etc
    foreach($all_lands_array as $country){
        if(in_array($country, $countries)){ //if a country name is found in $countries array, 
           //OPTIONALLY: exclude 'other'
            //if(in_array($country, $countries) && $country !='other')
            $found[] = $country; //store them in the $found variable
        }
    }
```

Test

```
$count_land = array('US'=>1,'DE'=>1,'BR'=>1,'FR'=>1,'other'=>1);
$all_lands_array = ["CN", "DE", "US", "EU", "RU", "BR", "GB", "NL", "LU", "other", "IT"];

var_dump($found);
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  string(2) "DE"
  [1]=>
  string(2) "US"
  [2]=>
  string(2) "BR"
  [3]=>
  string(5) "other"
}
```

Comment: i think thats the right way but it still just gives me : no match .. and i still need a clue how to save the output in another variable

Comment: well.. this kinda works but it just found one match.. it gives me "other" at an output but there should be at least 4 more :o

Comment: Added a your variables and I find all 3 + 'other'

Comment: i just dont know why but i just get an empty array

Comment: There must be something on your side like lower case vs upper case, for your question with the given data this is the answer

Comment: well not with lower/uppercase.. but i found the mistake like 5 minutes ago :) my mistake was that $all_lands array.. i needed to do a ' ' bevor and after the " " - like ' " DE " ' :) thanks for help anyway :)